# Definite article or none in "...at Taipei Zoo" or "... at the Taipei Zoo"?

Tags: articles, proper-nouns, toponyms

> 1. "Come see the baby panda, Yuan Zai, at Taipei Zoo"
> 2. "Come see the baby panda, Yuan Zai, at the Taipei Zoo."

In my opinion it should be the second choice. It belongs to a specific location and also follows what I would classify as an enclosed garden like environment, which are typically fronted by an article: e.g. "the botanical gardens". I can find examples of websites using both structures. In America there are also a number of examples of zoos following both patterns: Brookfield Zoo, also known as the Chicago Zoological Park.

Is there a pattern to follow here?

Comment: Both are correct.

Comment: Now that the title is more descriptive of the actual problem, the "Related" sidebar contains a better list of relevant existing questions, any of which may help. Do have a look through them. Do any in particular work for you?

Comment: I checked the sidebar and didn't find anything relevant. Before posting the question, I also did a search to try to find any related information here, as well as elsewhere. The closest rule I found was for gardens, which suggested that the definite article front the place's name. The examples I can find in usage go both ways, so it's hard to know whether there is a standard article placement convention for zoos.

Answer (score 2):

If the zoo is named *Taipei Zoo*, then the former is correct and the latter is not.  In that case, the latter would be correct as *at the Taipei zoo* (do not capitalize *zoo*).

Comment: Both of these citations are from the same article in Wikipedia: 

"The Taipei Zoo sometimes referred to as the "Muzha Zoo." 

"Taipei Zoo was founded in 1914, when Taiwan was under Japanese sovereignty, in Yuanshan Mountain (Maruyama) on the northern suburb of Taipei City."

Comment: Again, you should write *the Taipei zoo* or *Taipei Zoo*, not *the Taipei Zoo*.

Comment: Sorry, I think you are confusing the rules of capitalization for buildings with binomial nomenclature for animals. For buildings, if it is part of the name it is capitalized. The capitalization of animal names is different. Animal names depend on whether the name is based off of proper nouns or common nouns.

Comment: @RevlisLain Who mentioned buildings?  A zoo is not a building. And anyway, buildings do not have their own capitalization rules, AFAIK.  Is *Taipei Zoo* a **proper name**? If so, then drop the *the*. If not, then refer to it as *the Taipei zoo*.  You can say *the Foobar Database*, if you like, but typically what you would say is either *Foobar Database* (proper name, and no *The* as part of it) or *the Foobar database* (assuming that *Foobar* is a proper name. Same thing for proper names referring to zoos.

Comment: I invite you to Google the word zoo or to use a corpus, such as the Corpus of Contemporary American English.